# Found this error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/student"

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, mysql-connector

I was try to create simple java student `GUI` app in `IntelliJ IDEA` and its working fine.
Then I just try to connect database to inset all data into MYSQL,
so I create Schema(`student`) and Table(`appointment`) in `MySQL Workbatch`
and then connect that database in `IntelliJ IDEA Database` window
you can see in the picture and its successfully configured it.

Now I try to create connection via below line.

> Connection con =
> DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/student","root","root");

But this line give me this error
`Error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/student`

So I google it and I found this line.

> Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

but this line give this error
`Error: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Please everyone have a look in it, Its very helpful to me and other one who face this issue.

[image]

Comment: You should install the [mysql jdbc connector](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) library in your project for this to work

Comment: you need `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student`, note the missing colon

Comment: @ProGu, I modified it and run it... now I got this error
          Error: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Refer to comments from Kris, you need jdbc driver in your classpath

Comment: Thank you man its working now

Answer (score 0):

```
 private DBconnectionSingleton() throws SQLException {
    // create single instance of DB connection 
    Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
    connectionProps.put("user", login);
    connectionProps.put("password", password);// port & db name
    System.out.println("Loading driver...");


    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot find the driver in the classpath!", e);
    }

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student",
            connectionProps
    );
}
```